# How to find number of '1s' in an adjacency matrix in c programming?

Tags: c, adjacency-matrix

I have a 20 x 20 adjacency matrix and I would like to count the number of 1s in the ith row and jth column and display it as my output. I want my output to be like this:

```
Number of edges for each node: (for example)
Vertex 0: 3
Vertex 1: 4
.
.
.
Vertex 19: 10
```

This is my code for the adjacency matrix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define M 20
#define N 20
int main()
{
int i, j, x, a, b;
int G[20][20] = { { 0 } };
/*creaate random adjaceney matrix*/
printf("==================================================\n");
printf("Welcome to my Graph Processing tool!\n\n");

srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            G[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else {
            G[i][j] = rand() % 2;
            G[j][i] = G[i][j];
        }
    }
}
/*check whether the whole row equals to 0*/
for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if (G[j] == 0) {
        x = rand() % 20 + 1;
        G[x][j] = G[j][x] = 1;
    }
    /*print the matrix G*/
    else
    {

        printf("The adjacency for graph G is\n");
        for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                printf("%d ", G[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I would like to count the number of 1s in the ith row and jth column* - it would be either 1 or 0...

Comment: To see if a whole row or column is 0, setup a for loop with either the row or column constant and walk the opposite element.  If a non-zero is found, break early.  If you get to the end, all zero.

Comment: would you mind writing a code? im not really sure how to implement it in my codes

Comment: What you say that you want to output doesn't match with the output example that you give. Do you wan't the number of edges per node (degree) or do you want the numbers of 1s un the ith row and jth column (As Eugene Sh. says "This would be either 1 or 0")?

Comment: Hi this codes is actually for graph processing which an adjacency matrix represents. Basically the 1s in the ith and jth row represent the number of edges for each node. So for example there are 6 1s in the 1st row and column, I want the output to be "Vertex 1: 6". Is that clearer?

Comment: One source of error: code inside the j loop at the end also loops over j, which makes the outer loop only be run once.

Comment: i dont think theres any error in my codes, i have already run it and it seems to be working fine